# DecimalField Validation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to validate a `DecimalField` in Django

Trying in shell:

```
>> from django.forms import DecimalField
>> from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
>> f = DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
>> f.validate(11) # after this I should get an error
>>
```

But it does not show validation errors. It should throw an error because 11 is greater that 10, right?

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are 1 problem in field declaration.
if max_digits = 2 and decimal_places = 1, your max is 9.9 without the intervention of validators.

max_digits = 3 and validators for max = 10.0

Use **clean()** function:

```
>> from django.forms import DecimalField
>> from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
>> f = DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
>> f.clean(11.2)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: what is `validate` for then?

Comment: I think it's just use for Field class: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/fields/#Field