# How to limit values of IntergerField with Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, field, limit

i wonder if it's possible to limit values of an IntegerField with Django.

My code in forms.py :

```
class RatingForm(forms.Form):
    rate = forms.IntegerField(label='Noter')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DecimalField Validation in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322802/decimalfield-validation-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use max_value as specified in the django doc. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield

```
class RatingForm(forms.Form):
    rate = forms.IntegerField(label='Noter', max_value=100)
```

Comment: I have this Error : module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'PositiveIntegerField'

Answer (score 1):

```
  from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

  class RatingForm(forms.Form):
    rate = forms.IntegerField(label='Noter',
            validators=[
                MaxValueValidator(100),
                MinValueValidator(1)
            ]
         )
```

use django's built in validators

Comment: Thanks, I have to write that in forms.py ?

Comment: This is to validate the model, the OP asked about an `IntegerField` in a form.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min_value` and `max_value`, inside your form: see the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield)

Answer (score 0):

This code works :

```
class RatingForm(forms.Form):
    rate = forms.IntegerField(label='Noter', validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(0)])
```

Thanks all !!